# How to add default value for a column?

Tags: sql

I want to add the column Season ID to the Team table with the default referencing the None 
value in the Season table (I don't want to say default = ‘None’, rather the SeasonID of 
the row that has ‘None’ as the Season Year), place a foreign key constraint on that column. Finally I need to add the Fall 2012 foreign key value into the Season ID column.

Here is my team table

```
teamID      teamName
----------- ---------------
100         No Winner      
101         Purple Pilots  
102         Red Devils     
103         Silver Lions   
104         Blue Jackets   
105         Green Hornets  
106         Gold Dragons
```

Here is my Season table

```
SeasonID    SeasonName Year
----------- ---------- ----
100         None       0000
101         Fall       2012
102         Winter     2012
```

Here is what i tried to do but I can handle the referencing for another table as for default value

```
alter table team
add SeasonID int not null;

alter table team
add default 'None'
for SeasonID

alter table team
add constraint team_seasonid_fk foreign key (SeasonID)
references Season(SeasonID)
on update cascade
on delete cascade;


update team
set SeasonID = 101
where SeasonID = 'None';
```

How can I do it correctly?

Comment: What is the error,what is the database?

Comment: why none? set default as 0...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Your column is of type `int` so you cant assign 'none' as it's default value. I suggest you to have a trigger on table and after insert find the default record from Season table and update the inserted record, or writing `instead of insert trigger` to do it at once.